# Set playa entry dynamically

Tags: playa

I have set an extended set of segments based on playa parent/child relationships

http://example.com/template-group/template/playa-parent/playa-child

I would like retrieve the content of an entry based on segment 4 but

1. I'm not sure I can do this and
2. I'm not sure if what I am doing is
   right?

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="countries" dynamic="yes" limit="1"}
{exp:playa:parent dynamic="yes" limit="1" channel="cities"}
{title}
{/exp:playa:parent}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I expect cities to yield the entries title ("London") based on the following URL

http://example.com/template-group/template/england/london

[EDITED: Typo fixed for limit syntax]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question in case others have a similar issue.

I reverted to only using the {exp:channel:entries} tag with the url_title peremeter set to {last_segment} like this

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="cities"
    dynamic="no"
    url_title="{last_segment}"
}
```

Simple.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's a typo, but the first thing I noticed was your limit parameter is a minus, not an equal symbol to equal the value 1 on the channel entry pair tag. Countries are the parent as stated, so wouldn't you want to use?

`{exp:channel:entries channel="countries" dynamic="yes" limit="1"}
{exp:playa:children field="[your_country_field_relationship_to_city_entry]"}
{title}
{/exp:playa:children}
{/exp:channel:entries}`

P.S. With the exp:playa:children you can pretty much use any parameter the channel entries tag has available. So even a url_title parameter with segment_4 might work in this case.

Comment: Each City channel entry is attached to a Country channel entry via the playa field {country}. I would have thought at to use the Playa Children tag I would then have to attach every city to the countries channel entry?

The {exp:playa:children} tag returns no entries.

Comment: So you want a city to belong to multiple countries?

Comment: Have you tried removing the dynamic yes parameter from the playa:parent tag? Also, have you tried ditching the field parameter and just use the channel parameter?

Comment: The city belongs to only one country as only one entry can selected with the playa field.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried both these options with no success. The field parameter has no affect on a playa parent tag. The channel parameter applied to a playa parent tag yields only the first entry regardless of what property is applied to the dynamic parameter. I want it to display the same entry as shown in segment 4.